# Using group policy preferences to push a file to C:\Windows on a restricted user

Tags: windows-server-2008, groups, group-policy

We have a really old Video learning program that we need to run from the network for our students. However it uses Director Player 6.0 and the students get the error: "Unable to copy the driver file C:\Windows\xobglu16.dll to your Windows directory. Your disk may be full"

Now the solution I've read is to copy the files manually to each machine and mark them read-only.

I'm trying to do this via GPP, but the Event log is showing an Access is denied error. I believe it is because the student accounts do not have permission to c:\windows.

Any ideas on a work around without using a script?

Comment: Is there some reason why you aren't apply a computer policy, which operates in the system context?

Comment: I have tried it in a computer policy and User. Both give me the same error.   "The computer 'xobglu16.dll' preference item in the 'TEST - CMP - Secondary Software Deployment Group Policy object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070005 Access is denied.' This error was suppressed."

Comment: So I managed to solve the problem. For some reason the folder on the network share was not inheriting permission so the students didn't have access to the file... It was a complete bone headed move on my part to not notice that right away. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you haven't checked the "Run in user security context" box on the files you're pushing out. That would be on the "common" tab in GPP. If that is unchecked and you're still getting the error, it would be a very good idea to try and get this pushed out through the *Computer* GPP. Since these are probably student machines, they're likely in an OU that's full of them anyway.

Comment: Run in user security context is not check.  I have tried running it in a computer preference and a user preference both fail. The error I get on the client Event log is: "The computer 'xobglu16.dll' preference item in the 'TEST - CMP - Secondary Software Deployment Group Policy object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070005 Access is denied.' This error was suppressed." At least on the share side I am 100% positive that the correct permissions are in place.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 2 step process:

1. Copy the file(s) from the network share to %UserProfile% using the "Run in logged-on users's security context (user policy option)"
2. Copy the file(s) from the %UserProfile% to C:\Windows making sure the "Run in logged-on users's security context (user policy option)" is NOT selected

This works for me....

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is you have to specify the destination file name not just the destination path. I did this recently and once i put the full destination path and file name + extension it worked immediately.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this with Group Policy.  Your options are:

1. Write a script to copy from the network folder, however depending on your setup you may need to give your students access to write to C:\Windows
2. Push the file via an [SMS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc181665.aspx) package or another automated software delivery system.

Comment: Please see sysadmin's comment that suggests otherwise. In the GPP option, see: "Run in logged-on user's security context (user policy option)" changes the default user context. Normally preferences are processed using the Local System account (SYSTEM), selecting this option will make sure the user context is used instead. Network Drive and Printer Mappings ignore this setting as they always use the user context anyway.